# I want to hide badge notification in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, apple-push-notifications, badge

I want to clear/ hide badge notification in macOS.
I am using this code

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    application.dockTile.badgeLabel = nil
    application.dockTile.showsApplicationBadge = false
}
```

it's not working.
Any help

Answer (score -1):

You can try using :

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

**OR**

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Comment: The question is about macOS and `NSApplication`.

Comment: I have used this didn’t work for me ,How ever , NSApplication.shared.dockTile.badgeLabel  for me
2nd UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 doesn’t work for mac, As for MAC OS Apple doesn’t allow to UIKIT library